# Inconsistent behavior when calling same method from different event handlers

Tags: c#, .net, edsdk

I've built a little camera capture daemon which captures a sequence of images from an attached DSLR using Canon's EDSDK and [Wayne Hartman's C# wrapper](http://blog.waynehartman.com/archive/2009/01/07/edsdk-to-remote-control-your-canon-camera.aspx).

Capturing works great and very reliably when I call `takePhotograph()` from a test button click handler on the form itself. However, when I try to call `takePhotograph()` from `socketServer_MessageReceived()`, it's very unreliable and frequently causes the app stop responding. After tracing the call stack, it looks like the entire order of calls gets jumbled up, ultimately causing the EDSDK to hang up when calling `EdsDownload()` prematurely (before all images have been captured).

I'm coming from a non-multithreaded environment (Flex/ActionScript), and have a hunch I'm just doing something elementarily wrong related to my handlers.

Here's the gist of my code:

```
    private SocketServer socketServer;

    private void initSocketServer()
    {
        socketServer = new SocketServer();
        socketServer.Start( Convert.ToInt16( serverPortField.Text ) );
        socketServer.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<SocketEventArgs>( socketServer_MessageReceived );
    }

    private void socketServer_MessageReceived ( object sender , SocketEventArgs e )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "[CaptureDaemon] socketServer_MessageReceived() >> " + (String)e.Data );

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.RegisterConverters( new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() } );

        dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize( (String)e.Data , typeof( object ) );

        if ( (String)obj.destinationID != "captureDaemon" )
            return;

        switch ( (String)obj.messageID )
        {
            case "capture":
                takePhotograph( obj.body.successiveShotDelay , obj.body.successiveShots );
                break;
        }
    }

    private void testCaptureButton_Click ( object sender , EventArgs e )
    {
        takePhotograph( 500 , 4 ) );
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to wrap the `takePhotograph` with the `Form.Invoke` (`this.Invoke(...)`)? There's a chance that if it works from the GUI then it will also work when you force a correct thread for the call.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Great idea, that did it! It's definitely a work around, but I think it will serve my immediate purposes. I'm curious, what would be the best practice in this situation? Also, please do add an answer if you'd like the prize.

Comment: Perhaps "workaround" isn't quite right. It just seems strange that I would have to do that. Could very well be something weird with my "architecture" in this context.

Comment: Hard to say where exactly the problem was but glad that this common trick helps this time too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to wrap the `takePhotograph` with the `Form.Invoke` (`this.Invoke`)? There's a chance that if it works from the GUI then it will also work when you force a correct thread for the call.